# Remove empty patches from quick fur effect

Tags: hair

I would like to know if it is possible to remove these patches of empty space using the Quick Fur effect.

[image]

[image: enter image descriptio[![Details Panel]n here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3AV8.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3AV8.jpg)

[image: Details Panel 2]

[image: Details Panel 4]
[image]

Comment: What settings did you use? How does your mesh look like? Can you [edit] the question to add more details?

Comment: Thanks @Luciano... I have added the screens from the particles page :)